# How to get first, second, third and fourth Monday of each month?

Tags: php, date, datetime, recurrence

I'm working on an event based website. The user can create multiple events during the year and here is how the form works.

We have one select box with the following options :

- The first
- The second
- The third
- The fourth

And another select box with the names of the week days.

For example, he can choose to repeat his event every "second" "Monday" of each month during one year (or more).

Now, I'm looking for a way to get the date of each second Monday (as per the example above) with PHP.

I have this code which allows me to get what I want... But not sure about a great way to use it in a loop.

```
echo date("j, d-M-Y", strtotime("second monday 2017-11"));
```

Should I just loop over and change the year & month string?

Thanks!

Comment: the good thing is you only have to do it once for the hole year. and you could cache your values.

Comment: @swisswiss I forgot to mention that it can be on several years. Just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, this problem has been solved already. The [iCalendar](https://icalendar.org) standard has a Recurrence Rules component to deal with recurring events. There's an RFC specification, and there's an [official PHP implementation](https://github.com/zcontent/icalendar) as well. Alternatively, check out the [tplaner/When](https://github.com/tplaner/When) library on GitHub.